# At shortly vs shortly vs in short

Tags: grammar

There is a rumor that  this multinational company will  set up its regional headquarters in India - - - - -

At shortly

Shortly

In short

In this question we need to add "at" before "shortly" or in short  its OK without at

Comment: Definitely do NOT add an "at" before "shortly".

Comment: There's no "official" definition of how soon ***shortly*** might imply, but personally I don't think it works at all well in contexts where the future event is at least days (if not weeks or *months*) in the future. As a rule of thumb I'd say if something is happening *shortly*, it'll happen in a few seconds / minutes (almost always ***today***).

Comment: I think the usage and meaning of "shortly" depends on context.  If a receptionist at a doctor's office says to me, "Dr. Jones will be with you shortly," I certainly don't expect her to mean days or weeks!  On the other hand, if I read in the newspaper "The US and China are expected to sign a major trade agreement shortly", I don't expect that it means in the next few minutes!

Answer (score 1):

> There is a rumor that this multinational company will set up its regional headquarters in India **shortly**.

*shortly* used as an adverb is correct, meaning *soon*.

I cannot think of a usage for *at shortly* as a phrase in itself.

[*In short*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+short) is an idiomatic phrase meaning "in summary" or "to state briefly".
It is something like using [TL;DR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TL;DR) on the internet, when pointing to a summary of a long detailed passage.

Answer (score 0):

Time expressions ending in *-ly* are adverbs in themselves and don't need *at*.

> I will do this at 3:00.
>
> I will do this shortly (yearly, monthly, daily).